# after i redirect to page that render ejs page, the page dont render. why?

Tags: express, redirect, ejs, render

```
approval route:

const putApprovalForm = async(req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => { 
    try{
        let isComing = false;
        let numberOfPeopleArriving = 1;
        if(req.body.is_coming === 'true'){
            isComing = true;
            numberOfPeopleArriving = +(req.body.number_of_people_arriving)
        }else{
            numberOfPeopleArriving = 0;
        }

        const payload ={
            arrival_confirmed: isComing,
            number_of_people_arriving: numberOfPeopleArriving
        }

        const  invited_id  = req.params.invitedId;
        
        const invited = await Invitees.findByIdAndUpdate(invited_id, payload , { new: true});

        res.redirect(303,'/api/thankyou'); 
    }catch(err){
        console.log(err);
        
    }


thank you route:
const getThankYouPage = async(req: Request, res: Response, next: NextFunction) => {
    console.log('thank you page');
    res.render('home.ejs');
}


home.ejs:

<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<%- include('partitial/head.ejs') %>
<body>
    <h1>Thank you</h1>
</body>
</html>
```

so when i redirect to thank you route, it console 'thank you page' but not render the home page.
when i inspect my page in the network tab in preview tag i see the thanl you page.

how can i fix it?